# helm double quote annotations value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to quote my annotation values. I am trying like this

```
annotations:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
     {{ $key }}: {{ printf "%s" $value | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

and this

```
annotations:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
     {{ $key }}: "{{ $value }}"
  {{- end }}
```

this is my values.yaml

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: false
```

but it is not working. Even if I double quote the annotation value in values.yaml helm is removing the quote. Can somebody tell me how can I get helm with double quote values in annotation?

I am using Helm version 3.

Comment: Have you tried the quote function? Something like: `{{- range $key, $value := quote .Values.ingress.annotations }}`

Comment: @OhHiMark, it is giving some different error now. range can't iterate over "map[kubernetes.io/ingress.class:nginx nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol:HTTPS nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect:false]"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try this:

```
annotations:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
     {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: what is your helm version?

Comment: I am using helm 3.

Comment: @user3847894 This solution is correct solution. If it's not working, probably something else is wrong. Can you share your template and values files, so we could reproduce your problem locally?

Comment: @user3847894  can you double quote the annotation value in values.yaml and use    ```{{- toYaml .Values.ingress.annotations | nindent 4 }}``` , ? check if this is working for you.

Comment: All the solutions that is here in this page either by @hoque or by me(in question) are working just fine. There is something else that is wrong and I will need to figure that out.